# Using startup commands when the default startup disc is not OSX

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup

I have to use a startup command (ie command - S for single user mode) when restarting my computer, but this is proving to be impossible, as the startup disc is windows by default on my computer - unless I hold option at start, I cannot choose to go into OSX, and when I hold the startup command I want without holding option, my computer just goes into windows - it doesn't work when I hold a startup command after I choose to run OSX, either.

Additionally, I cannot get into my system preferences to change the startup disc, as I cannot login (which is part of the reason why I need to use a startup command in the first place). I cannot change the startup disc on windows, either.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

OS is Lion, w/ a 2006 Mac Pro

Answer (score 1):

You can boot to the Lion recovery partition by holding the <kbd>option</kbd> key during the reboot.  From there, you can select the startup disk, similarly to if you were running system preferences.

From there, the single-user mode boot should work as you expect.